# Nasm on OS X replace int 0x80 with subroutine

Tags: macos, nasm

I'm trying to understand what exactly happens when you call a subroutine on an OS X machine (because that's what I have in front of me). I'm using `nasm` version 0.98.40.

I read a few tutorials mostly targeting other platforms and noticed that a few of them had the definition

```
_syscall:
    int 0x80
    ret
```

So, I tried a simple hello world with and without that subroutine but otherwise identical.

I'm struggling to understand why `call`ing a subroutine is not "equivalent to" directly using its body in this case. I don't think I'm disturbing any of the registers that the system call needs.

Here are the two assembly files.

```
; without_subr.asm
section .text
global start

start:
    push dword msg.len
    push dword msg
    push dword 1
    mov eax,4
    sub esp,4
    int 0x80

    add esp,16

    push dword 0
    mov  eax, 1
    sub  esp, 12
    int 0x80

section .data

msg:    db 'Hello, world!',10
msg.len:   equ $ - msg
```

and with the subroutine:

```
; with_subr.asm
section .text
global start


_syscall:
    int 0x80
    ret

start:
    push dword msg.len
    push dword msg
    push dword 1
    mov eax,4
    sub esp,4
    call _syscall

    add esp,16

    push dword 0
    mov  eax, 1
    sub  esp, 12
    int 0x80

section .data

msg:    db 'Hello, world!',10
msg.len:   equ $ - msg
```

When I assemble, link, and run `without_subr.asm` everything works as intended:

```
$ nasm -f macho without_subr.asm 
$ ld -o without_subr without_subr.o
$ ./without_subr 
Hello, world!
```

However, `with_subr.asm` produces nothing and exits abnormally

```
$ nasm -f macho with_subr.asm 
$ ld -o with_subr with_subr.o
$ ./with_subr 
Exit 1
```

Comment: Check out this [little tutorial](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html). The system calls on MacOS are implemented similarly to BSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `call` a subroutine, the return address is pushed onto the stack. The extra value on the stack leaves the values you `push`ed beforehand in the wrong place.